# MySQL random number record based on date & time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to select a random record based on date and time for a class. If a class has more than 1 time slot for the day I want to select that and then move to the next day and do the same for each day going forward. Up to a week is scheduled. I get how to get a random record using RAND() in MySQL but how can i then go thru each day using same code? I have looked around and found questions close but nothing with date and hour.

Data example:

```
Classroom  Start_Date Start_Time
        1     6/6/18    1700
        1     6/6/18    1800
        2     6/7/18    1200
        2     6/7/18    1300
        2     6/7/18    1400
```

I only 1 record per day per classroom. I have this so far and I am pretty sure I need to create a previous and next record. But cannot figure out how to get that to work. Code I have so far is below. Thanks in advance for your help.

MySQL code:

```
         SELECT CLASSROOM, n,start_date, start_hour
         FROM
          (SELECT @prev:='', @n := 0) init
        JOIN
          (select @n := if(2a.CLASSROOM != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := 2a.CLASSROOM
       , date_format(2a.START_DT_TIME, '%m/%d/%Y') as start_date
       , 2a.CLASSROOM + CASE WHEN 1a.TIME_ZONE_KEY = 'America/Chicago'        THEN Hour(CONVERT_TZ(2a.START_DT_TIME,'GMT','America/Chicago'))
             WHEN 1a.TIME_ZONE_KEY= 'America/Denver' THEN Hour(CONVERT_TZ(2a.START_DT_TIME,'GMT','America/Denver'))
             WHEN 1a.TIME_ZONE_KEY= 'America/Los_Angeles'THEN hour(CONVERT_TZ(2a.START_DT_TIME,'GMT','America/Los_Angeles'))
             WHEN 1a.TIME_ZONE_KEY = 'America/New_York'THEN hour(CONVERT_TZ(2a.START_DT_TIME,'GMT','America/New_York'))
             WHEN 1a.TIME_ZONE_KEY = 'America/Phoenix'THEN hour(CONVERT_TZ(2a.START_DT_TIME,'GMT','America/Phoenix'))
             ELSE Null 
             END AS start_hour
      from XX_WELCOME_SESSION_0 1a
       JOIN XX_WELCOME_SESSION_0_CLASS 2a
        ON 1a.ACCOUNT_ID=2a.ACCOUNT_ID
      where 2a.START_DT_TIME > NOW()
    ORDER BY 2a.CLASSROOM
    ) x
  WHERE n <=1
  ORDER BY CLASSROOM, n
 ;
```

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain by storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I wish i could but it is not my data. I have to get it to work for reports for the business side to use.